# Rewrite this array manipulation using a lambda function?

Tags: c#, lambda, refactoring

I have this routine which alters all elements within an array...

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sOutputFields.GetUpperBound(0); i ++)
    {
        sOutputFields[i] = clsSQLInterface.escapeIncoming(sOutputFields[i]);
    }
```

`sOutputFields` is a one dimensional `string` array. `escapeIncoming()` is a function which returns a `string`.

I thought this could be re-written thus..

```
    sOutputFields.Select(el => clsSQLInterface.escapeIncoming(el));
```

..but this appears to do nothing (though does not throw an exception). So I tried..

```
    sOutputFields = 
       (string[])sOutputFields.Select(el => clsSQLInterface.escapeIncoming(el));
```

..but I get this exception at execution time..

**"Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'."**

how to fix?

Comment: Query results are immutable, and => is not a assigment operator.

Comment: Your LINQ code does not rewrite, rather it creates a new collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type is an IEnumerable, you need to convert to an array:

```
sOutputFields = sOutputFields.Select(el => clsSQLInterface.escapeIncoming(el)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks :) I see the ToArray<string>() is not required, just ToArray(). Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

A Select doesn't return an object that can be explicitly cast to an array. You'd need to do `sOutputFields.Select(el => clsSQLInterface.escapeIncoming(el)).ToArray<string>()` in your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
sOutputFields = sOutputFields.Select(el => clsSQLInterface.escapeIncoming(el)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sOutputFields = sOutputFields.Select(el => clsSQLInterface.escapeIncoming(el)).ToArray();
```